# Simple WebView App on Kotlin with API 33 using Android Studio Flamingo

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, webview

WAfter browsing the internet, watching a few YouTube videos, I've to admit, that I'm at the end of the road. Amongs plain wrong, and/or outdated instructions, there's not much left to do than to turn to the community in hopes someone actually has an up-to-date solution.

I'll update this main thread accordingly to display the "correct" code once we're done.

I've used the following video, relatively recent, which results in a working app on the emulator, but does not allow for generating a signed app bundle. I'd assume it's the closest solution to making this work and being able to build a basic-webview app. Even the Android Studio Documentation offers a solution which results in an unresolved reference.

Source (a):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mLsLwqpDoE4

Source(b):
https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/webapps/webview

Code:

MainActivity

```
package com.sloth.hub

import android.R
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.webkit.WebView
import android.webkit.WebViewClient
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import com.sloth.hub.ui.theme.SlothHubTheme


class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    private var myWebView: WebView? = findViewById<View>(R.id.webView) as WebView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            SlothHubTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background) {
                    Greeting("Android")
                }
            }
        }
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(WebViewClient())
        myWebView.loadUrl("https://app.sloths.one")
        val webSettings = myWebView.getSettings()
        webSettings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    }

    class myWebClient : WebViewClient() {
        override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView, url: String, favicon: Bitmap) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon)
        }

        override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView, url: String): Boolean {
            view.loadUrl(url)
            return true
        }
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        if (myWebView!!.canGoBack()) {
            myWebView!!.goBack()
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed()
        }
    }


}

@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Text(
            text = "Hello $name!",
            modifier = modifier
    )
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun GreetingPreview() {
    SlothHubTheme {
        Greeting("Android")
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Errors:

```
e: /home/dgriffin/AndroidStudioProjects/SlothHub/app/src/main/java/com/sloth/hub/MainActivity.kt: (23, 63): Unresolved reference: webview
e: /home/dgriffin/AndroidStudioProjects/SlothHub/app/src/main/java/com/sloth/hub/MainActivity.kt: (28, 18): Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type WebView?
e: /home/dgriffin/AndroidStudioProjects/SlothHub/app/src/main/java/com/sloth/hub/MainActivity.kt: (29, 18): Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type WebView?
e: /home/dgriffin/AndroidStudioProjects/SlothHub/app/src/main/java/com/sloth/hub/MainActivity.kt: (30, 36): Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type WebView?
---
org.gradle.api.GradleException: Compilation error. See log for more details
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Compilation error. See log for more details
```

Comment: Better if you don't update the question with the fixed code, if that's what you mean. Correct code can go in an answer below. That way we have both the problem and solution here for future readers.

Comment: You definitely cannot do this: `private var myWebView: WebView? = findViewById<View>(R.id.webView) as WebView` That will make your app crash after you do fix the compilation errors. `findViewById` can  only be called *after* you set a content view. You also seem to be mixing together traditional views and Compose. You never set your content to the traditional views, so there is no WebView in your activity.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that there is a mix of "old" and "new", as 99.9% tutorials are completely outdated and even platforms that charge upwards of €1000 /m and are top-rated on google, use an outdated API Level in their outputs. So, yes, not being an android, but a vue developer, I've no clue how to achieve this with the latest API level in Android Studio.

Comment: I'd say this really is not / should not be rocket science and "any" Kotlin developer that is up to date on his stuff, should be able to help me (us) solve this :D

Comment: I don't personally use WebView in any of my apps so I can't walk you through that. But, your issues so far have nothing to do with WebView specifically. (1) You need to read [this page](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html) of the Kotlin documentation about nullability. That will help you understand most of your compile errors. (2) You need to firmly decide if you're using Compose or not. Android's built-in view system is the standard that's been used since the beginning. WebView is a part of that and there is no counterpart in Compose. (continued...)

Comment: Compose only came out of beta in the past year (and frankly, IMO should still be considered beta because of some performance issues with scrolling lists). The old view system isn't getting deprecated, so there's no problem with not using Compose. You can wrap a WebView in a Compose hierarchy, but it will be more complicated to use that way, and definitely not worth it if you don't have a complex UI surrounding your WebView.  So, if you decide not to use Compose, you should delete the `setContent { }` block and use `setContentView` with the id of the XML layout you made.

Comment: See, I know what you're trying to say. As the instructions on the Android documentation also says you can use setContentView. But when using the exact example from the Android Dev page, you simply get reference errors to activityContext
val myWebView = WebView(activityContext)
  setContentView(myWebView)

Comment: It says use "something similar to the following". It's example code. They expect you to know what a Context is from the more introductory Android documentation. The reason they put `activityContext` is because your code could be in an Activity class or in a Fragment class, and you retrieve the context differently depending on which class you're in. Since your code is in an Activity, you would replace `activityContext` with `this`, since an Activity *is* its own context.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a super simple example that you could test out...

```
package com.sloth.hub

import android.os.Bundle
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient
import android.webkit.WebView
import android.webkit.WebViewClient
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        supportActionBar?.hide()

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val myWebView: WebView = findViewById(R.id.webView)

        myWebView.loadUrl("https://app.sloths.one")

        myWebView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()

        myWebView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        val myWebView: WebView = findViewById(R.id.webView)
        myWebView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
        if (myWebView.canGoBack()) myWebView.goBack() else super.onBackPressed()
    }
}
```

I definitely agree how much of a pain it can be. I had tried various examples with no avail when I first started. And now I'm stuck again and looking for some answers on Stack Overflow :) This code above has worked for me for some basic use.
Also, be sure to put the following in your AndroidManifest.xml: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`

Answer (score 0):

I don't use WebViews, so I can't go beyond explaining how to get it into your Activity.

You already have an XML layout created that has a WebView in it, so you just need to set that layout as your content view, and afterwards use `findViewById` to get the reference to put in your property. Your property needs to be `lateinit` so it won't have to be nullable. We use `lateinit` for properties that we cannot initialize until `onCreate()` but are definitely not null once they have been initialized.

Since you have an XML layout, you can delete all the Compose stuff.

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    private lateinit var myWebView: WebView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        myWebView = findViewById(R.id.webView)
        myWebView.webViewClient = myWebViewClient() // I assume you meant to instantiate your own class, not the superclass WebViewClient
        myWebView.loadUrl("https://app.sloths.one")
        val webSettings = myWebView.settings
        webSettings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    }

    // Keep the other code you had below the onCreate function

}

// You can delete the Composable functions.
```

You can also use the `apply` scope function to clean it up a bit:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    myWebView = findViewById(R.id.webView).apply {
        webViewClient = myWebViewClient()
        loadUrl("https://app.sloths.one")
        settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    }
}
```